# Having coroutine wait for previous calls

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I still haven't fully grasped Kotlin coroutines yet.

Basically I want a coroutine to wait for any previous calls to finish before executing. The following code seems to work. But is it doing what I think it's doing?

```
private var saveJob: Job? = null

fun save() {
    saveJob = someScope.launch {
        saveJob?.join()
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // suspending database operation
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the code is doing what I want. But is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `launch`ed code is concurrent to the code outside it. That means that what you wrote has a race condition: the outside code may have already assigned the new job to `saveJob` when you try to `join()` it, resulting in a deadlock.

I guess what you want is to trigger a `save` operation in the background, and the operation itself will pull all the data to save from somewhere else. You probably don't want a queue of `save` jobs, just ensure that everything is saved at the point you call `save()`. If you called `save` a bit earlier and a new save job hasn't yet started, those two calls can be coalesced into a single `save` operation.

Furthermore, you say that you have a *suspending* database operation. Suspending code doesn't belong in the `IO` dispatcher, which is there only if you have to perform many *blocking* operations concurrently.

All told I'd suggest using an actor:

```
val actor = someScope.actor<Unit>(capacity = CONFLATED) {
    // suspending database operation
}

fun save() = someScope.launch {
    actor.send(Unit)
}
```

Comment: I will try and figure out actors and see if I can use them. Learned a lot from your answer already though, thanks. But one thing I do find curious is not using Dispatchers.IO for this, using it for suspending functions is all over googles android docs (for example for database and network calls).

Comment: Can you please point me to a link? There could be some detail there that I can notice and explain it. I hope the docs aren't flat-out wrong :)

Comment: I found [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5), for example. It says `Start using Room and coroutines in your app, the database work is guaranteed to be run on a non-UI Dispatcher.` That sounds like a) the database impl is still blocking code, but b) they automatically transfer it to a background thread, so no need to explicitly switch to `Dispatchers.IO`. I saw the usage of `Dispatchers.IO` in the docs as well, and honestly i think the examples are wrong (maybe they made sense before but it changed in the meantime).

Comment: That article is wrong though. If you start a blocking room call on the UI thread the app crashes with this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` This is mentioned [here in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) (at the top in the second highlighted box). But isn't `Dispatchers.IO` exactly made for this kind of thing?That is, waiting for disk/network responses?

Comment: The article isn't wrong, it describes this scenario: `Asynchronous queries—queries that return instances of LiveData or Flowable—are exempt from this rule because they asynchronously run the query on a background thread when needed.`. As of version 2.1 Room added a `suspend fun` layer on top of these async calls. Yes, `Dispatchers.IO` is made for blocking calls, however Room already has its own dispatchers and will automatically use them when you use its coroutine support.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's not wrong. Although I would recommend just to go imperatively just as you program outside of a coroutine. Saving the response in the variable would ensure that the next line won't execute until the response of the first:

```
scope.launch(someDispatcher){
  val dataFromDelayingCode = getDelayingData()
  if(delayingData.isFinished){

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not waiting for any data. It is just a fire-and-forget database save. But when the user fires them in rapid succession, sometimes an old value gets saved after a new one and overwrites it (if I don't wait).